# Data Error When Trying to Create a Primary Partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I'm trying to install Windows 10 to my computer via USB. I am in the command prompt via Repair mode through the Windows ISO. I've run the following commands:

- start diskpart
- select disk 0
- clean create partition primary

This is where I get the following error:

> DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy
>   check).

I've tried to run a chkdsk on C:, but it returns no problems. Anyone know what else could be wrong?

Comment: Why are you in the command prompt? Why don't you just run the regular install for Windows 10?

Comment: I am not able to allocate a partition via the regular install either

Comment: Then I would suggest you do a check of the disk. Remove it and hook it up to another computer.

Comment: As I stated above, the chkdsk revealed no issues

Comment: You ran the chkdsk with /F/X/R flags?